# Any ideas on how to have a generic class, implementing a protocol, be cast to that protocol and allow retrieving a property?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a simple `Result` object which should contain an object (class, struct or enum) and a `Bool` to say whether it was cancelled or not. I need to interrogate this object along its path (before it gets to its destination, where the destination knows what kind of object to expect) to determine whether it was cancelled or not (without worrying about the accompanying object at that moment). My object looks like:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol Resultable {
    var didCancel: Bool { get }
}

class Result<T>: Resultable {
    let didCancel: Bool
    let object: T?

    init(didCancel: Bool, object: T?) {
        self.didCancel = didCancel
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

The idea being that my `Result` object can wrap the `didCancel` flag and the actual object (which can be of any type), and the fact that it implements the `Resultable` protocol means that I can interrogate it at any point to see whether it was cancelled by casting it to `Resultable`.

I understand (while not liking it) that the protocol has to be prefixed with `@objc` so that we can cast to it (according to the Apple docs). Unfortunately, when I run the code below (in a playground or in a project), I get a nasty `"does not implement methodSignatureForSelector:"` error message:

```
let test = Result(didCancel: false, object: NSArray())

println(test.didCancel)
// transform the object into the form it will be received in
let anyTest: AnyObject = test

if let castTest = anyTest as? Resultable {
    println(castTest.didCancel)
}
```

It seems that despite the protocol being prefixed with `@objc`, it also wants the actual class to inherit from `NSObject` (and this is not a requirement that Apple makes explicit). This is obviously a problem for a generic class.

Is there anything I am missing here? Any way to get this to work? Failing that, are there any workarounds (although I strongly believe that this kind of thing should be possible - perhaps we can hope that Apple will do away with the `@objc` protocol casting requirement at some stage)?

**UPDATE**
It looks like this is solved with [Swift 1.2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/)
You can now cast to a non-ObjC protocol, and without the object having to inherit from NSObject.

Comment: Marking all the stuff @objc is the workaround. Swift itself doesn't support down casting because it lacks the dynamic capabilities to do this. The way I understand it you just never use this dynamic approach where some component reflects on incoming objects and adjusts the processing based on the capabilities. Instead you do the reverse of 'id' and try to keep the type as complex as possible for as long as possible. Presumably using generics/overloading. Eg the last thing could be something like 'func doIt<T>(a:T)' and 'fun doIt<T: Resultable>(a: T)' instead of doing the 'as?'. Not sure.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using overloading in that way, but unfortunately this would not work for me, because I need to be able to get the `didCancel` in a context where `T` is unknown (only `didCancel` is interesting to that part of the code) and further down the line there would be code that knows what `T` is.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you here. Isn't the whole point of using T that the actual type is unknown? :-)

Comment: Yes and no - the object is the result (obviously ;) ) of an action which will be passed back down the chain of callers. I should also point out that the Result object is passed through ReactiveCocoa signals, so arrives as an `AnyObject`, not a `Result`. So the intermediate caller needs to be able to cast it knowing that it has a `didCancel` property but not knowing the type of the other property, and the original caller can then cast it knowing the type of the other property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that despite the protocol being prefixed with `@objc`, it also wants the actual class to inherit from `NSObject`

This is not true. For example, the following code works as expected:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var flag: Bool { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    let flag = true
}

let foo:AnyObject = MyClass()
if let p = foo as? MyProtocol {
    println(p.flag)
}
```

The problems is that: Any methods/properties declared in Swift Generic classes are invisible from Objective-C. Hence, from the perspective of `@objc protocol Resultable`, `didCancel` property declared in `Result<T>` is invisible. That's why `methodSignatureForSelector:` is called.

The workaround here is very annoying: You have to have *non Generic* base class for `Result` that implements `didCancel`.

```
@objc protocol Resultable {
    var didCancel: Bool { get }
}

class ResultBase: Resultable {
    let didCancel: Bool
    init(didCancel: Bool) { self.didCancel = didCancel }
}

class Result<T>: ResultBase, Resultable {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                         You have to explicitly conforms `Resultable` here as well for some reason :/

    let object: T?

    init(didCancel: Bool, object: T?) {
        self.object = object
        super.init(didCancel: didCancel)
    }
}

let test = Result(didCancel: false, object: NSArray())
let anyTest: AnyObject = test
if let castTest = anyTest as? Resultable {
    println(castTest.didCancel) // -> outputs "false"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for both the explanation and the solution. I think I will just get rid of the protocol and do my testing by casting to `ResultBase`, since the purpose of my protocol was simply to be able to get `didCancel` without knowing what the object was. I do hope Swift gets to support dynamic casting in this way without relying on Objective C.